# Is there a better way to mask a Credit Card number in python?

Tags: python, string

So I have a csv file that contains full credit-card numbers.. We dont need the full number, and so I am writing a quick script to parse through the csv and replace the cc number with a masked representation. (all *'s except the last four).  I am pretty new to python and hacked this up, and it works, but in order to learn I want to know if it could be done easier.

Assume that "str" will be a full creditcard number.  But for the sake of my example I am just using the string "CREDITCARDNUMBER".

```
str = "CREDITCARDNUMBER";
strlength = len(str)
masked = strlength - 4
slimstr = str[masked:]
print "*" * masked + slimstr
```

The output is exactly what I want

```
************MBER
```

But I am sure there is a more elegant solution. :) Thanks!

Comment: by looking at this i'm guessing you an shorter the code 1~2 lines

Comment: why not just print the last 4 numbers? are the asterisks necessary?

Comment: You might want to accept one of these answers

Comment: So far I wouldn't call the answers more "elegant". They are shorter, but a bit cryptic I think. In general I might prefer the code in the question for readability.

Answer (score 23):

Neater still:

```
>>> s = "CREDITCARDNUMBER"
>>> s[-4:].rjust(len(s), "*")
'************MBER'
```

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps slightly more elegant:

```
card = "CREDITCARDNUMBER"
print ("*" * (len(card) - 4) + card[-4:])
```

Note that I've avoided using the name `str` because that is already the name of the built-in string type. It's usually not a good idea to use names that shadow the built-in names.

Answer (score 9):

For those who want to keep [Issuer Identification Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_card_number#Issuer_identification_number_.28IIN.29) (IIN) (previously called the "Bank Identification Number" (BIN)), which is usually the first 6 digits, that should do the job:

```
print card[:6] + 'X' * 6 + card[-4:]
'455694XXXXXX6539'
```

Answer (score 5):

With [Format String](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings) and [Slicings](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#index-34):

```
'{:*>16}'.format(card[-4:])
```

Comment: sweet!, i modified it a bit to deal with dynamic length `('{:*>'+str(len(card) - 4)+'}').format(card[-4:])`

Answer (score 0):

You could make it a little shorter like so:

```
str = "CREDITCARDNUMBER";
print "*" * (len(str) - 4) + str[-4:];
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a flexible way to mask stuff, so I thought I'd share ...

```
def mask(string, start=0, end=0, chunk=4, char="*"):

    if isinstance(string, str):

        string_len = len(string)

        if string_len < 3:
            return "input len = {}, what's the point?".format(string_len)

        if start <= 0 or end <= 0:
            start = string_len // chunk
            end = start

        if string_len <= 4:
            mask_len = string_len // 2
            start = 1 if mask_len - 1 == 0 else mask_len - 1
            end = start
        else:
            mask_len = string_len - abs(start) - abs(end)

        return string[:abs(start)] + (char * mask_len) + string[-end:]



if __name__ == "__main__":

    s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234567890a0b0c0d0e0f1a1b1c1d1e1f2a2b"
    l = [i for i in s]
    message = "ip: {}\nop: {}\n"
    section = "-"*79

    print("\nSTRINGS")
    print(section)
    print(message.format(s[:4], mask(s[:4])))
    print(message.format(s[:3], mask(s[:3])))
    print(message.format(s[:2], mask(s[:2])))
    print(message.format(s, mask(s)))
    print(message.format(s, mask(s,start=2,end=4,char="#")))
    print(message.format(s, mask(s,start=3,end=3,char="x")))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get a decently readable solution without worrying about the `len` of the `str` using a simple regex replace and two string slices:

```
import re
str = 'CREDITCARDNUMBER'
print(re.sub('.', '*', str[:-4]) + str[-4:])
```

I am not sure this is more "elegant" than the original, but there it is.

Answer (score 0):

We also can use this function:

```
def maskify(cc):
    if len(cc) < 4:
        return cc
    return "#" * (len(cc)-4) + cc[-4:]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
#Simple code to mask 16-digit credit card number

def cardNumberHider():
    str = input("Enter the card number: ")
    masked = len(str) - 4
    slimstr = str[masked:]
    print("Your masked card number is: ", end="")
    print("*" * masked + slimstr)
cardNumberHider()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).